# Didn't find class "kotlin.text.Charsets" error using okhttp-3.12.0 Android

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, okhttp

There is nothing wrong with codes so i'm just copying the error. i'm using okhttp 3.12.0 to get something from the internet (in Android Programming)

next line probably is the main problem:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.text.Charsets"
```

or

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                         Process: com.example.infitualer.ipdemo, PID: 3306
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/text/Charsets;
                                                                             at okio.Buffer.<clinit>(Buffer.kt:2212)
                                                                             at okhttp3.ResponseBody.create(ResponseBody.java:210)
                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:62)
                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Util.java:0)
                                                                             at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:127)
                                                                             at com.example.infitualer.ipdemo.MainActivity$IpTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                             at com.example.infitualer.ipdemo.MainActivity$IpTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.text.Charsets" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.infitualer.ipdemo-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                             at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                             at okio.Buffer.<clinit>(Buffer.kt:2212) 
                                                                             at okhttp3.ResponseBody.create(ResponseBody.java:210) 
                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:62) 
                                                                             at okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Util.java:0) 
                                                                             at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:127) 
                                                                             at com.example.infitualer.ipdemo.MainActivity$IpTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                             at com.example.infitualer.ipdemo.MainActivity$IpTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:25) 
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use  Kotlin stdlib dependency for Okio.
Either use Okio 1.1.15 which is what OkHttp depends on or include the Kotlin stdlib which is a dependency of Okio 2.0.

Download [Okio 1.1.15.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.15.0) from MvnRepository and add it to lib folder, then configure dependency

```
implementation files('libs/okio-1_15_0.jar')
```